# What does "we have a clear interest" and "rely on our legitimate interest" mean?

Tags: meaning

> We have a legitimate interest to use your information in this way to
>   make sure that we are able to help you find the right destination and
>   start to plan the best safari holiday for you. Where **we rely on our
>   legitimate interests**, we’ll always ensure that your rights are
>   protected.
>
> It is in our legitimate interests as a business to use your data in
>   this way, for example, **we have a clear interest** in ensuring that
>   our website works properly.
>   (https://www.katsam-adventures.com/privacy-policy/)

What does the bold part mean? Does "we rely on our legitimate interest" mean "we conduct for our legitimate interest"? 
Does "we have a clear interest" mean "we are clearly interested in..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this piece is stongly influenced (I believe) by a piece of legislation called GDPR - much of the wording is intended to replicate what you will see there, and is therefore a form of 'legalese' rather than 'normal' English.

Specifically: "we rely on ..." means we (believe that we) are allowed to do 'this stuff'.

"we have a clear interest"  means: "we think it is obvious that we need to do 'stuff' as part of our normal business operations ..."

Part of the reason that this is a little confusing, is that what they state as obvious may not be entirely obvious to the 'Data Subject' (i.e. YOU) and/or you may not even agree with what is stated.